# How to solve this card game turn requestes clashing issue

Tags: javascript, turn-based, node.js, socket, poker

So I am developing a poker card game using JS +node.js + socket.io.

It is turn-based game. There will be a host and 4 other players.The flow is the players need to make a yes/no choice, then the host need to make a yes/no choice upon players' move, then players will need to make another yes/no choice, then the server will determine who wins.

Put simply,

1:Host set up the hand ----->2: inform all players----> 3:A player make a move(ticking yes or no) --> 4:this move will show up on the host's screen--->5:the host need to make his/her move(ticking yes or no)--->6: the host's move show up on players' screen, they make another yes/no choice----> 7:the server determine who wins.

**The issue lies on step 5.**

There will be multiple moves waiting for the host to process. Now the current design is all moves are shown by the form of a custom confirm box. It has yes/no button. It works perfect when there is only one host and one player. But when there is more than 2 players, there is a serious clashing problem.

If player A makes a move, it shows on the host's screen, and before the host ticking anything, player B makes a move and then player B's move (confirm box) will replace player A 's confirm box. In this case the host will not be able to process player A's move and the game cannot finalise.

How to get this clashing issue sorted? I hope I am not making this issue sound too complicated but I have been scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a queue of decisions to make which is processes first-in-first-out. You can easily implement it as an array in JavaScript.

When an event happens which requires a decision and the decision window is already open, that new decision is [pushed to the end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) of the decision queue.

When the player made the decision, the current decision window is closed. You check if there are elements in the decision queue, and if there is you [remove the oldest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) decision from the queue and reopen the window with that decision.